# how to copy the current file full name to global clipboard in vim

Tags: vim

I want to get: when press F10, then copy the full name of the current file to global clilpboard

So I used the following mapping, but it doesn't work:

```
map <F10> :let "+ = expand("%:p")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`:let @`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#%3alet-@) to write to a register:

```
:noremap <F10> :let @+ = expand("%:p")<CR>
```

I default to [`:noremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3anoremap), so that my mappings don't call other mappings unintentionally.

End with [`<CR>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#carriage-return) for best results.

Answer (score 2):

```
" Convert slashes to backslashes for Windows.
if has('win32')
    nmap <F10> :let @*=substitute(expand("%:p"), "/", "\\", "g")<CR>
else
    nmap <F10> :let @+=expand("%:p")<CR>
endif
```

Via: [Copy filename to clipboard](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_filename_to_clipboard)